# Native armeabi libraries not being installed but they are in the APK

Tags: android, android-ndk

I hope I'm not duplicating any other post, but I can't find anything similar to my case.
I'm creating a service that depends on 3rd party native libs for an Android automatic payment terminal (PAX A920) using their PAX Neptune Service. The libs are still for "armeabi", which is deprecated, but their demo app works fine.

Now, I've included this native libs under `src/main/jniLibs/armeabi`. I unzipped the built APK file and found them under `lib/armeabi` as expected.

However, when I install the APK they don't appear on the device under `/data/app/com.mypackage.myservice/lib/arm` as they do for their demo app.

This is causing my service to crash when their API tries to load the libraries.

I even tried to add

```
ndk {
    abiFilters "armeabi"
}
```

in build.gradle and even added `android.useDeprecatedNdk=true` in gradle.properies.

No good. The libs are available in the APK but they won't install on the device.

Inspecting the demo app code, there is nothing different from my configurations and they don't even use the abiFilters nor the useDeprecatedNdk.

Any suggestion on how to solve this problem?

EDIT: Thanks Alex. I renamed the directory to "armeabi-v7a" and it is now working!

Kind regards

Comment: Most likely, the demo app has a very low `targetSdkVersion` declared in the manifest. The point is that the Android platform applies all kinds of backwards compatibility shims based on this number. With pretty good confidence, you can simply move these libraries to `src/main/jniLibs/armeabi-v7a` and the APK will work. But this still cannot be published on Play Store, because they require 64-bit libs.

Comment: Many many thanks! @AlexCohn. They were targeting 28, which is strange. But renaming the directory to "armeabi-v7a" did work!

Comment: Let's close this question, so that for other users it can be easier to find.

Answer (score 0):

With pretty good confidence, you can simply move these libraries to src/main/jniLibs/armeabi-v7a and the APK will work. But this still cannot be published on Play Store, because they require 64-bit libs.